# Why has PhpStorm 2016.2 stopped pre-filling "Search Everywhere" from selected text

Tags: phpstorm

I have recently upgraded to PhpStorm 2016.2 on MacOS X and sadly quite a few things have got worse.

Previously (v10.x) if I selected some text, then double-tap shift, when the search-everywhere dialogue pops up it had the selected text pre-filled and it would be already searching. This was a super-quick way to find stuff, as it was almost always the first option that was correct.

Now you have to select, copy, double-shift, paste, enter - which is several times more work. For such a frequent task I can already feel the RSI building.

I have looked in the preferences, but cannot see anything relevant.
I've also searched [their help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/searching-everywhere.html) but it doesn't mention this feature.

Comment: I've removed `osx` tag as this is not Mac-specific issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why has PhpStorm 2016.2 stopped pre-filling “Search Everywhere” from selected text

Because users were asking for this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-147128

> I have looked in the preferences, but cannot see anything relevant.

AFAIK there is no such setting.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157100 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

I suggest to (at very least) vote for this ticket .. and maybe even ask your friends (who use this IDE and miss such feature) to do the same. More votes -- higher the chance of implementing it.

Comment: It's amazing how people's preferences can be so polarised. Thanks I'll certainly vote on getting an option for this to be returned. How sad!

Comment: I've added a vote and will certainly encourage my team to cast their opinions.

Comment: Consider voting for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146791 as that fixes it for both parties.

Comment: Closure: the ticket was implemented and it was re-instated in 2017.1 - I'm using the prefill happily again now.